# How can I compare two fields in a filter?

Tags: views, 9

Since Drupal 9 no longer has the *Globals: Fields Comparison* option (as Drupal 7 did) in the view's filter section, how can I compare two fields?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3155249

Comment: That just might do the trick, thanks.  I'll apply the patch and see what happens.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment on my question, there is a patch that restores this functionality, which did the trick.

Comment: On which question is that?

Comment: The comment is on this question (the one from you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patch here: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3155249 restores the field comparison functionality in views and solved my issue.